# Adding a class between when user scrolls between 200px and 300px only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a class to div when a user scrolls down the page. When they scroll `200px` down the page I want a class to be added and then once the user scrolls down `300px` I want the class to be removed. Similarly, when the user scrolls back up the page and is `300px` from the top, I then want the class to be added until it gets to `200px` and then removes the class.

I've tried so many variations but I think I'm approaching it all wrong. Here's a jsfiddle of how far I've gotten so far - http://jsfiddle.net/v8my3sr1/

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() { 
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 200) {
    $(".trigger").addClass("wow");
  } else {
    $(".trigger").removeClass("wow");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You condition is incorrect. You should check that `scroll` value is between `200` and `300`

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() { 
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (300 >= scroll && scroll >= 200) {
    $(".trigger").addClass("wow");
  } else {
    $(".trigger").removeClass("wow");
  }
});
```

```js
$(window).on('scroll',function() { 
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (300 >= scroll && scroll >= 200) {
    $(".trigger").addClass("wow");
  } else {
    $(".trigger").removeClass("wow");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 2000px;
}
.trigger {
  margin-top: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}
.wow {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="trigger">
    <h1>Trigger container</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you can use `.toggleClass()` to simplifying code

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() { 
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(".trigger").toggleClass("wow", 300 >= scroll && scroll >= 200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @mohammad! So simple when I look at it like that! Will accept as the answer in 10mins when it lets me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop();

   $(".trigger").each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > cutoff){
      panel.removeClass('wow');
      $(this).addClass('wow');
      return false;
    }
  })
})
```